# Failing to authenticate Calendar permission in consent screen

Tags: azure, office365

I have written an application that uses office365 REST api's to sync calendars, emails and contacts. For OAuth during the testing phase I had created a common application in Azure AD with permissions enabled for Calendar, Mails and Contacts. Now to push this application for production I want to create two different applications in Azure one for Contacts and mails and other for Calendar.

I successfully created the applications but when I try to authenticate Calendar sync, it shows me consent screen with permissions only for calendar and when I click "Accept" in consent screen I get this as response,

```
Array
(
[error] => temporarily_unavailable
[error_description] => AADSTS90090: A transient error has occurred.    
                       Please try again.
                       Trace ID: 9bf71aee-6acc-4443-b999-8eaf58ef0f3d
                       Correlation ID: 720d3469-de71-4f03-9703-
                                       5f5cc6374232
                       Timestamp: 2015-02-18 09:50:11Z
)
```

The other application created only for Contacts and Mails works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still seeing this issue? Just asking as it appears to be reported as transient error, which typically means that this is intermittent and might go away.

Comment: I am trying to repro the problem, but am very unsuccessful, meaning I always get successful an AccessToken. Can you tell me the exact permission you are configuring. I tried with various one by one, incl. "Calendars.Write" only.

Comment: E.g. if you want to try it: https://code-flow.azurewebsites.net/Home/. Will put the code on git-hub for reference soon: https://github.com/mattleib/o365api-simple-code-flow

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried again by creating new application by enabling only Contacts and Emails. After I click "accept" in consent screen, the page remains idle for >1min and I get same error "temporarily unavailable". I posted this in community and still no luck. I have one more application created a month ago and it works like a charm. But the new application that I create now throws this error. Was there any changes done recently?